# Insert records in to join table where missing Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have tghe following tables:

role:

```
id
name
description
```

permission:

```
name
description
```

role_permission:

```
id
role_id
permission
can_read
can_create
can_update
can_delete
```

I would like to insert a record in role_permission for each role and permission, for example if I have the following permissions:

```
Client
Employer
```

And the following roles:

```
ClientAdmin
EmployerAdmin
ClientViewer
EmployerViewer
```

I need a script which will insert records in to the role_permission for each role and permission combination e.g.

```
1, ClientAdmin, Client, 0, 0, 0, 0
2, ClientAdmin, Employer, 0, 0, 0, 0
3, EmployerAdmin, Client, 0, 0, 0, 0
4, EmployerAdmin, Employer, 0, 0, 0, 0
5, ClientViewer, Client, 0, 0, 0, 0
6, ClientViewer, Employer, 0, 0, 0, 0
7, EmployerViewer, Client, 0, 0, 0, 0
8, EmployerViewer, Employer, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

I can't for the life of me work it out, any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

To add clarification, if I have 35 roles, and I add some new functionality I create a permission for that functionality, I would like to call a procedure / script to add a role_permission for every role and permission, with the can_read/update/create/delete all set to 0 so not currently active until I set that.

But if there is an easier way to do this and keep control, I'd be interested.

My goal is that I have several roles which some can edit and update some can only read data for certain objects.

My front end is Angular and backend will be Lambda and MySQL, API focused so I'm building the API before I put functionality on the front end.

So a user signs in, has a role and depending on that role the user can do functions, e.g. admin, can do everything, but client admin can only modify client records and client view can only read and not modify records.

If that makes sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After messing around with this for a while, I may have come up with a solution for you. From what it sounds like, you want to dynamically concatenate and insert a number of rows based on the criteria of what values exist in the `role` and `permission` tables. You can use a procedure that utilizes nested while loops to insert the records. The number of iterations for the outer loop is based on the number of distinct permission names in `permission` to the exponent of that number (so 2 would be 2^2, 3 is 3^3, etc.). I use the `POWER()` function for that. The inner loop iterates through the permissions while staying on the same role based on the index of the outer loop. I use a couple of `LIMIT` clauses for that to make sure only one row is selected and it is at the proper index.

I still want to validate this is the output you want. From what I understand, every concatenated `role_and_permission` (we'll call it) must be assigned each `permission` that exists. Why? For a `role_and_permission` like "ClientViewer" to have both an "Admin" and "Viewer" permission doesn't seem to make sense. But if this is the output you want, please confirm.

```
create table `role`(`id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT, `name` varchar(30), `description` varchar(100) NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
create unique index `roleIndex` on `role`(`name`);
create table `permission`(`id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT, `name` varchar(30), `description` varchar(100) NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
create unique index `permissionIndex` on `permission`(`name`);
create table `role_permission`(`id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT, `role_id` varchar(30), `permission` varchar(30), `can_read` bit(1), 
`can_create` bit(1), `can_update` bit(1), `can_delete` bit(1), PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_ROLE` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `role`(`name`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_PERMISSION` FOREIGN KEY (`permission`) REFERENCES `permission`(`name`));
create unique index `rolePermissionIndex` on `role_permission`(`role_id`, `permission`);
insert into `role`(`name`) values('Client');
insert into `role`(`name`) values('Employer');
insert into `permission`(`name`) values('Admin');
insert into `permission`(`name`) values('Viewer');
drop procedure if exists iterate_through_roles;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE iterate_through_roles()
BEGIN
   DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE iterations INT DEFAULT 0;
   SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `name`) FROM `permission` INTO n;
   SET i=0;
   SET iterations = POWER(n,n);
   WHILE i<iterations DO
     SET @j=0;
     WHILE @j<n DO
         insert into `role_permission`(`role_id`, `permission`, `can_read`, `can_create`, `can_update`, `can_delete`)
         select CONCAT(r.`name`, p.`name`), (select `name` from `permission` group by `id` having min(`id`) > @j limit 1) as name, 0, 0, 0, 0
         from (select `name` from `role` limit i,1) r
         join `permission` p;
         SET @j = @j + 1;
     END WHILE;
     SET i = i + 1;
   END WHILE;
END; //
DELIMITER ;
CALL iterate_through_roles();
SELECT * FROM role_permission;
```

A link for the script I made can be found [here](https://paiza.io/projects/U5Kbk8glMfCRNnefB8dLug?language=mysql).

Comment: Hi Max, thank you for your time this has given me some insight however I am looking for a script or sql statement to select all from the role table and and the permission table and insert records in to the role_permission where there isn't one.  Can this be achieved?

Comment: If I knew all of the current data in the three tables and what data exists in the `role` and `permission` tables that is not in the `role_permission` table, that would certainly be helpful. But, I can tweak my code a little and see what I come up with.

Comment: @RichC See my edit - I updated the link as well.

Comment: Thabks, that was pretty much what I was looking for.

Comment: @RichC Good to hear.